# Java InputStream read multi part message

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a task. From InputStream I should receive multi part message. First four bytes it is message length, and other bytes it is message body. At the same time can receive many messages. For example:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

there is

```
1,2,3,4 - length(in this case 4), 3,4,5,6 - body
7,8,9,10 - length (6), 11,12,13,14,15,16 - body
```

and so on

Length I compute by this method:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paRawBytes, int piOffset, boolean pbBigEndian) {

    int iRetVal = -1;

    if(paRawBytes.length < piOffset + 4)
        return iRetVal;

    int iLowest;
    int iLow;
    int iMid;
    int iHigh;

    if(pbBigEndian)
    {
        iLowest = paRawBytes[piOffset + 3];
        iLow    = paRawBytes[piOffset + 2];
        iMid    = paRawBytes[piOffset + 1];
        iHigh   = paRawBytes[piOffset];
    }
    else
    {
        iLowest = paRawBytes[piOffset];
        iLow    = paRawBytes[piOffset + 1];
        iMid    = paRawBytes[piOffset + 2];
        iHigh   = paRawBytes[piOffset + 3];
    }

    // Merge four bytes to form a 32-bit int value.
    iRetVal = (iHigh << 24) | (iMid << 16) | (iLow << 8) | (0xFF & iLowest);

    return iRetVal;
}
```

And more:

```
private static void getEventsList(byte[] bytesFromInputStream) {


    int start = 4;

    int end = getLength(bytesFromInputStream) + 4;

    byte[] tmp;

    tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesFromInputStream, start, end);


    eventsArrayList.add(tmp);

    if (bytesFromInputStream.length > end) {

        byte[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesFromInputStream, end, bytesFromInputStream.length);


        getEventsList(newArray);
    }


}

private static short getLength(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteUtils.byteArrayToInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, 4), 0, true);
}
```

But it is not working and I have not more idea. Help me please

Comment: What is the output right now (that is wrong)? Might help in debugging...

Comment: First, have you tested your `byteArrayToInt` method with some example inputs? The bitwise operations don't look quite right to me. There are some example implementations in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa)

Comment: byteArrayToInt work fine, first two messages read good, but other has incorrect length

Comment: I need recursive function. I never know how many parts I receive in time

Comment: It's possible to do this either recursively or iteratively, though doing it recursively is a bad idea if there may be a very large number of messages, as you may cause a stack overflow.

Comment: This doesn't compile, unless you have another implementation of byteArrayToInt()? The method takes an offset, but the invocation doesn't provide one...

Comment: Sorry, I forget )) I update getLength() method, offset should be zero

Answer (score 1):

The code you originally provided doesn't quite seem to compile (maybe that was the problem you were having, but you didn't really specify)?

To fix it, I had to get `getLength()` to return a `short` by casting the result of `byteArrayToInt` to `short`. Or you could just return an `int` instead. I removed the static reference to `ByteUtils` because I put all the methods into one class.

I also added an offset of `0` to the call to  `byteArrayToInt` so the method signatures match.

After that, your code seems to work, at least for a few simple cases, e.g:

```
byte[] message = new byte[]{0,0,0,1, 1, 0,0,0,2, 2,3};
getEventsList(message);
```

produces:

```
Got a message of length: 1
Content 1
Got a message of length: 2
Content 2
Content 3
```

(I added some `println` statements too)

Your `byteArrayToInt` method does not seem to work correctly for large values (more than 16 bits). There are some example implementations (including some one-liners) in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa).