# convert ArrayOFByte to int []

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a `ArrayOfByte`

```
Log.d(TAG, "arrayOfByte :"+arrayOfByte); // it will display arrayOfByte :[B@2b052c60

Log.d(TAG, "arrayOfByte :"+ Arrays.toString(arrayOfByte)); //it displays arrayOfByte :[1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

now i want this `[1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` into some `int[ ] series` ie:

```
 int[ ] series ={1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

So how this can be done??

I used

```
 int[]intArray = new int[1024];
 intArray = ByteBuffer.wrap(arrayOfByte).asIntBuffer().array()
```

but getting exception as below:

```
04-24 11:32:34.750: E/AndroidRuntime(4927): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
04-24 11:32:34.750: E/AndroidRuntime(4927): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-24 11:32:34.750: E/AndroidRuntime(4927): at java.nio.IntToByteBufferAdapter.protectedArray(IntToByteBufferAdapter.java:169)
04-24 11:32:34.750: E/AndroidRuntime(4927): at java.nio.IntBuffer.array(IntBuffer.java:109)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7619111/1339473 to ByteBuffer

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work, try hard-coding it:

```
int[] intArray = new int[arrayOfByte.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfByte.length; i++) intArray[i] = (int)arrayOfByte[i];
```