# 2 byte array in Little Endian to int without java.nio.*

Tags: java, endianness

I want to convert 2byte array in Little Endian to Int without using java.nio.*. How can I accomplish this?

With regards

Comment: Copy the logic of the code in `java.nio` and use it.

Comment: very good suggestion, I didn't think about it :D

Comment: Also you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa

Comment: Have you tried bit wise operators?

Comment: @George: Problem is in converting 2 byte array to Int, it gives negative value

Comment: @George: I read just now that I must use 0xff to give only unsigned values. Is that true?

Comment: Doing `byte & 0xff` is a trick to get the unsigned value of a byte, yes.

Comment: No problem. You figured it out for yourself :)

Comment: `&` and `<<` is pretty much all you need.  (Well, maybe the occasional `+` or `|`.)

Comment: @HotLicks : certainly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick `int val = (anArray[1] & 0xff) << 8 + (anArray[0] & 0xff);`

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this post and realised that the accepted answer will not work correctly because `+` has a higher precedence than `<<`.

Therefore it should be `int val = ((anArray[1] & 0xff) << 8) + (anArray[0] & 0xff);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 Byte means 16 bit
because in Little indian The least significant 16-bit unit stores the value
you can use bitvise operations in java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html