# Altering specific bits of a 32-bit integer in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

**Background:** I have a 32-bit integer with a binary representation like so:

```
1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

*Note: This is the binary representation of the ARGB value of `Color.BLUE`. I'm using this for illustration purposes, but it is relevant to a situation I am attempting to solve.*

**The Problem:** I am attempting to alter the high order bits so that its binary representation looks like this:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

Or more simply, the first eight high order bits should be changed like so:

```
1111 1111 -> 1000 0000
```

**Current Solution Attempt:** Thus far, I've been successful by masking out the first eight high order bits, and then "adding" the desired value using bitwise "or", like so:

```
int colourBlue = Color.BLUE.getRGB(); // equal to binary value at top of question
int desiredAlpha = (0x80 << 24); // equal to 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

// Mask out the eight high order bits, and add in the desired alpha value
int alteredAlphaValue = (colourBlue & 0x00FFFFFF) | desiredAlpha;
```

While this does presently work, admittedly it has been some time since my computer architecture classes, and I have not had a lot of experience yet working with bitwise operators and lower level bit manipulation.

**My question:** Is my solution the correct way to accomplish this task? If it is in some way improper (or just plain "dumb"), what is a better (or correct) way to achieve the goal of altering specific bits?

Comment: You know your solution would also wipe out the red and the green parts, if there were any, right?

Comment: Your approach is correct if your bits are arranged as ARGB with 8 bits each.

Comment: @user2864740, your approach wouldn't change the high bits to 0x80 if they were 0x00 to start with.

Comment: @DavidWallace Hmm, I just made an attempt with a completely random colour (random RGB values), and it does not appear to change anything other than the highest order bits, as I intended. No code was changed from what I posted. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: @StevenHansen That's correct, each component is indeed 8 bits each.

Comment: @Teeg Your approach is correct.  You will not wipe any RGB bits with the mask you specified.

Comment: Why are you actually trying to twiddle the bits? what problem are you trying to actually solve with this?

Comment: You've got the general idea.  Play with it a little.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I misread your code.  Please ignore my earlier remark.  You're doing this exactly the right way.

Comment: @DavidWallace No worries, you forced me to re-examine with a different dataset, which is never bad.

Comment: @MattD That's a rather large issue on its own. Our application receives tile bitmaps from a geoserver to be placed over top a google map android map. Unfortunately geoserver does not set opacity of the tiles (as far as we can tell); this must be done client-side. Unfortunately, android does not seem to have the usual `BufferedImage`-type classes I would normally use in Java, with the exception of [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), which does not do what I need.

Comment: if the alpha is always 0x80 you can simply use `alteredColor = color & 0x80ffffffff;`

Answer (score 2):

Transcoded from C# to Java (untested):

```
public static int setBits(int orig, int newBits, int startBit, int length)
{
    int mask = Mask(startBit, length);
    return (orig & ~mask) | (bits << startBit & mask);
}

public int Mask(int startBit, int length)
{
    if (length ==32)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else
        return (1 << (1 << length) - 1) << startbit;
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can just specify the mask directly, and avoid the bit-shifting:

```
public static int setBits(int orig, int newBits, int mask)
{
    return (orig & ~mask) | (bits & mask);

}
```

Of course, if you're being handed the RGB value as a 32 bit number, you could always [convert it to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619058/102937) and vice versa, which makes the manipulations much easier.

Comment: If this is going to be done a lot you might improve performance by creating a two-dimensional array of masks up front

Comment: Actually, it is unlikely you will improve performance this way in Java.  1)  The number of possible masks to precompute could be intractable.  2) The cost of an array fetch in Java includes a bounds check - an extra fetch of the length + 2 comparisons.  3) For a 2-D array, the fetch overheads are (at least) doubled.  4) A large array fetch (with a random index) is going to give you a cache miss, etc.  By contrast, bitwise operations are register to register.