# Search Token Occurrence count and Row Count Simultaneously in SQLite FTS3/4

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

I am quite new to android and SQLite and having trouble to count the token occurrence and no of rows containing the token. What I have found is
COUNT() Function and 
getCount() Function

Both only return the no of rows containing the token. I need to calculate the token occurrences also i.e if token is present in 5 tables rows but in row 3 token occurs 2 times I need to display 6 occurrences instead of 5.

Sorry for improper formatting if any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this information with the `x` argument of the [matchinfo function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#matchinfo).

Comment: Yes, Exactly but no information is provided in the documentation about the manipulation of Blob return type. Furthermore its conversion to other data types is giving errors!

Comment: Are you asking how to [convert a byte array to integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa)?

Comment: Yes. I used hex(matchinfo(Table-name)). It provided hexadecimal representation of byte array. As I have many columns so the hexadecimal notation seems hard to get manipulated.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help as it paved my way to the solution I needed.