# Migrate a int conversion from byte from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, int, arrays

I have the following piece of code in C++

```
int magic;
stream.read(&magic, sizeof(magic));
```

Which stores the value of magic from an array of bytes.

I want to migrate it to Java, so far I have this:

```
int magic = stream[0];
```

But it is not working. I think that it is due to the length of the ints in Java and C++. Shall I use two bytes in the Java part to retrieve the proper magic number?

Comment: What you are trying to do here, is slightly more complex in java than it is in C++, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7619111/3447831

Comment: An `int` in Java is 32-bit and always 32-bit.  An `int` in C++ does not have to be 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] stream = ...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(stream);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int magic = buf.readInt();
```

See [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). A java `int` is always 4 bytes signed, and per default java uses a BIG_ENDIAN byte order, so you might want to set a reversed order.