# how to reverse the bytes inside the buffer using java

Tags: java, byte, netty

I have a buffer contains Two bytes lets imagine the buffer is: `org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer` buffer[28,29,30,31,32] to 
read the two fisrt bytes in java we use this function :

```
buffer.readShort()
```

but what i want to do is to read the buffer from 29 to 28(i want to reverse the order of the bytes).

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of you code, so that we can see the problem

Comment: take a look above, the post is updated

Comment: If readShort is reading from the `currentIndex` to `currentIndex + short.length`, just reverse the loop to read from `currentIndex + short.length` to `currentIndex` (and decremente the index used)

Comment: @YoussefAssnai filling more numbers to the buffer is not shedding any light on your question ;) What class is `buffer`? Bow do you initialize it? How do you read from it?

Comment: how to do that?? is there java built function can do that??

Comment: @YoussefAssnai without the code, I don't know, what is `buffer`, is it from an API ? If so, what is it returning, a `Byte[]` ?

Comment: take a look above :buffer is an instance of  ChannelBuffer its a java object

Comment: You mean `org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer` ?

Comment: AxelH exactly..yess thats what i meant

Comment: you have any solution for me please??

Comment: if you need any information i can provide it just ask

Comment: Finally.... you should have told that. We can't guess it. And stop spamming, edit the comments ;)

Comment: so...is there any solution please??

Comment: Use [this](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html) as a reference and use either big endian or little endian HeapBuffer according to your need to change the byte order. hope this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not your objects, you will have to read the `Byte` yourself using [`readByte`](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#readByte()).

For a Short, create an array of `Byte[2]` and call the method twice to fill it :

```
byte[] shortByte = {
    channel.readByte(),
    channel.readByte()
}
```

Then reverse it or simpler

```
byte[] shortByte = new byte[2];
shortByte[1] = channel.readByte();
shortByte[0] = channel.readByte();
```

Then, from this, you just need to create the Short from this array. You can see how from the following post : [Convert a byte array to integer in java and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619058/4391450)