# How can I convert a length 4 byte array to an unsigned int?

Tags: scala

I'm reading in bytes from a binary file like so

```
import java.io.FileInputStream

val fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)

val byteArray = new Array[Byte](4)

fis.read(byteArray)
```

How can I then convert the bytes in byteArray to an unsigned int?

Comment: That depends on what that bytes represent

Comment: @Piro How so? In the documentation for the file it says the 4 bytes represent an unsigned int.

Comment: I do not see any documentation to refer to. integer can be represented in 4 bytes in a lot of ways. @twentyseven already assumed bytes represent 4 digit characters. That brings encoding into game. Then integer can be stored simply as 32bites binary number, and many more

Comment: @Piro Oh I see what you're saying. The file is binary encoded.

Comment: Binary encoded via what protocol?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's a file from the bitcoin blockchain http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DaJcdsyqQSs/UsiTXNHP-0I/AAAAAAAATC0/kiFRowh-J18/s1600/blockchain.png.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
def bytesToInt(bytes: Array[Byte], littleEndian: Boolean): Int = {
  val buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
  if (littleEndian) buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt
  else buffer.getInt
}
```

Whether the bytes are little endian or big endian is a question of how they were written.  If the bytes are in some weirder ordering (unlikely, but possible if the protocol dates back to 16-bit days), then something a lot more involved is required.